# Data Blending equivalent in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a similar concept as Tableau's Data Blending in Power BI?  I have 2 tables with different granularity, lets say Table A has Target Revenue data on monthly basis for a Region and Table B has Revenue data on Daily bsis for a Region.  If I join by Region, it will show Target multiple times (as many days there are in the month).
Thanks

Comment: So you wants to union both table?

Comment: That sounds like a table join